# Apache Solr - Need to index the same documents two times for plain text query to work

Tags: indexing, solr

I have a dataset of 76000 big json documents. I have it indexed into solr with post.jar

```
java -jar -Dc=sampleindex -Dauto example/exampledocs/post.jar "/home/sample/sample.json"
```

I am able to see that the 76000 documents are indexed in the solr UI dashboard. I can do field base search against the index like below

if customer_name is one of the field, I can search with

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/sampleindex/select?fl=customer_name&q=customer_name%3Arachel
```

I get the results from solr. However, when I just search using only (plain text)

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/sampleindex/select?q=rachel
```

I don't get any results.

I need to index the 76000 documents again and now the total document count is 152000

Now, if I search with with plain text "rachel"

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/sampleindex/select?q=rachel
```

I get results.

I am not sure if some thing is wrong with the way I am indexing.

Comment: When you don't have a field name in your query, the `df` - default field - is used. If the default field is a different field than what you're expecting, then there might be no hits. However, indexing the same content again shouldn't change that - but maybe the reason for the missing documents is something else. An old searcher might be used for the first set of queries if the new searcher isn't ready yet (i.e. not warmed up, if you have warming queries), and it's just the delay from the new indexing process that makes it available (so waiting the same amount of time would do the same)

Comment: However, you should also be careful about having a proper `id` field, so that reindexing the same content doesn't give you double the amount of documents. In that case you won't be able to update existing documents properly with new content, so either add an `id` field that's unique for each document or use something like de-duplication where a hash is created for each document, based on its contents (i.e. an id-like field).

Comment: For field less queries you should really consider using `defType=edismax` instead, it's usually better for "natural" user queries, paired with `qf=field1 field2 field3` - where the fields are the fields you want to search. It also allows you to weigh the fields differently. I'll move these comments to an answer if they solve your issue :-)

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh thanks for the suggestions. I will try your suggestion and let you know.